# Button is not enabling even after filling all fields?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

**As I am new in bootstrap and trying to build a feedback form. Everything is working fine but after filling all the fields the "send message" button is not enabling. I have tried many times but some mistake has been made by me which I am not getting. Even I tried by only having the FullName field in my form but even though the same error is occuring. Please help me in resolving this small issue**.

```
  <div class="container"><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 mb-4">
          <h3>Give Us Your Valuable Feedback</h3>
          <form [formGroup]="feedbackFormGroup" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="userfullname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">FullName</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userfullname" formControlName="fullname">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['fullname'].invalid && (feedbackFormGroup.controls['fullname'].dirty || feedbackFormGroup.controls['fullname'].touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['fullname'].errors.required">
                Field is <strong>required</strong>.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['fullname'].errors.pattern">
                Only <strong>alphabets</strong> allowed.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="userphonenumber" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mobile Number</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-prefix">+91</span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="userphonenumber" formControlName="mobile">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].invalid && (feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].dirty || feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].errors.required">
                Field is <strong>required</strong>.
              </div>
              <div
                *ngIf="!feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].errors.required && feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].errors.minlength || !feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].errors.required && feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].errors.maxlength">
                Please enter 10 digits.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['mobile'].errors.pattern">
                <strong>Invalid</strong> mobile number.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" [formControl]="email">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">{{getErrorMessage()}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="usermessage" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Your Valuable Message</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="usermessage" rows="7" formControlName="message"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['message'].invalid && (feedbackFormGroup.controls['message'].dirty || feedbackFormGroup.controls['message'].touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="feedbackFormGroup.controls['message'].errors.required">
                Field is <strong>required</strong>.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit"
                [disabled]="feedbackFormGroup.pristine || feedbackFormGroup.invalid">Send Message</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**And my component.ts file is here**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-feedback',
  templateUrl: './feedback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feedback.component.css']
})
export class FeedbackComponent implements OnInit {

  feedbackFormGroup:FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.feedbackFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      fullname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
      mobile:['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern('[6-9][0-9]*')]],
      address:['',[Validators.required]],
      message:['',[Validators.required]]
    });

  }

  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'Field is required.' :
        this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' :
            '';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a required `address` form control in your form group, but no address input field in your template.

So the user can't possibly enter any address.

So your form is always invalid.

Answer (score 0):

1) As i can see you have declared address as part of form and which is required as well but in your template you have not used address so your form is invalid.

2) One more thing As i can see in your component file you have defined email as an individual formcontrol field i think you need to move it with other formfields like message
address etc

3) Just for debugging if you check

```
 {{feedbackFormGroup.value | json}}
```

in your template file you will get

```
{ "fullname": "", "mobile": "", "address": "", "message": "" }
```

it does not include email as part of your form

Check below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcgp61